# Passing values to onExit template in an argo workflow

Tags: kubernetes, argo-workflows

I've stumbled upon a problem when using some more complex argo workflows with initialization and clean-up logic. We are running some initialization in one of the initial steps of the workflow (e.g. creation of some resources) and we'd like to perform a clean-up regardless of the status of the workflow. `onExit` template seems to be an ideal solution (I think that clean-up is even mentioned in argo documentation as predestined for tasks of the `onExit` template).

However, I haven't found a way yet to pass some values to it. For example - let's say that in the initialization phase we created some resource with id `some-random-unique-id` and we'd like to let the `onExit` container know what resources it needs to clean up.

We tried the `outputs` of some steps, but it seems that `steps` are unknown in the `onExit` template.

Is there a built-in argo mechanism to pass this kind of data? We'd like to avoid some external services (like key-value storage service that would hold the context).

Answer (score 2):

You can mark output parameters as global using the `globalName` field. A global output parameter, assuming it has been set, can be accessed from anywhere in the Workflow, including in an exit handler.

The example file for writing and consuming global output parameters should contain all the information you need to use global output parameters in an exit handler.

https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/blob/master/examples/global-outputs.yaml

Answer (score 0):

Please share if you found a cleaner solution.

I see this workflow example for exit handler with parameters, which may resolve your issue: [Exit Handler with Parameters](https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/-/blob/examples/exit-handler-with-param.yaml?L21)

One method I found was to add steps to the template I want to call the exit template on, and call the exit template as the last step so I can access steps variables. I changed the original template to an inline template so the structure does not change too much, just involves adding the last step call to the exit template. Unfortunately, this does not utilize the actual onExit method.
[Inline steps template example](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/master/examples/steps-inline-workflow.yaml)

1.https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/-/blob/examples/exit-handler-with-param.yaml?L21

2.https://raw.githubusercontent.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/master/examples/steps-inline-workflow.yaml